# How can Java class extend Kotlin library

Tags: java, kotlin, class, extend

How can Java class extend Kotlin library?

I understand what all kotlin classes are final.

I have library and I need to override some methods.
But then I extend library, I'm getting error

```
public class Editor extends EditorLibrary //error Cannot inherit from final
```

Any chances to extend kotlin final class, because I can't change it to open?

Comment: maybe **Decorator** pattern will help in this case, https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator

Comment: You can't extend a final class.  If it's final, then it was designed to _stop_ you from extending it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have control over the library you can open the class for extension using the `open` keyword, otherwise, as you've mentioned, the class was not built for extensions...

```
open EditorLibrary(...) {
}
```

In such case you might consider using composition over inheritance... e.g. :

```
public class Editor {
    private final EditorLibrary editor;
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, I haven't control on it.

Comment: I've added an alternative to the answer, you can use composition here instead of inheritance, however if you don't control it you can extend the class itself